# Gradient Descent loss and accuracy doesn't change through iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using keras to implement a basic CNN emotion detection. here is my model architecture

```
def HappyModel(input_shape):
    X_Input = Input(input_shape)

    X = ZeroPadding2D((3,3))(X_Input)
    X = Conv2D(32, (7,7), strides=(1,1), name='conv0')(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name='bn0')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    X = MaxPooling2D((2,2), name='mp0')(X)

    X = Flatten()(X)
    X = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fc0')(X)
    model = Model(inputs = X_Input, outputs = X, name='hmodel')

    return model


happyModel = HappyModel(X_train.shape[1:])
happyModel.compile(Adam(lr=0.1) ,loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
happyModel.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 50, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

it appears that the model loss and accuracy doesn't change at all in every epoch step. it feels like the gradient descent stuck on local minima as follow:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQX47.png

have tried using Adam and SGD optimizer, with both learning rate .1 and .5, still no luck.

it turns out if I change the compile method command parameters, the model would converge nicely on training epoch
   `happyModel.compile(optimizer = 'adam' ,loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Keras documentation says that if we write the parameter this way, it would use the default parameters for adam (https://keras.io/optimizers/)
    `keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)`

but then, if I change the model compile method to the default parameters
   `happyModel.compile(Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, decay=0.0),loss= 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

accuracy and loss still stuck.
what's the difference between the two different implementations of Adam optimizer on Keras?

Answer (score 0):

You can check a closed issue on official keras-team page:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5564

You probably have a syntax issue, since the two ways are not completely equivalent.

Comment: ah, this could be it,  haven't find the solution though